# Why does ‘lūdīs’ end in a short syllable in Ov. Ep. Sapph. 16?

Tags: vowel-quantity, accusative, ovidius, metre

In Ovid’s *Epistulae* 16.152–153, the following two lines are found (‘eligiac couplet’, I believe is the term in English):

> mṓre tuǽ gentī́s nitidā́ dum nū́da palǽstrā̆ 
>    lū́dis et és nūdī́s fḗmina míxta virī́s.

(I used *æ* for the now more common *ae* in order to be able to place the diacritic for stress.)

For now, I have landed at this translation:

> When, according to the custom of [your] countrymen, whilst in the wrestling ring, naked,
>    in the games you were a woman mixing with naked men.

I take *nūda* to go with *fēmina*, *nūdīs* to go with *virīs*; I take *nitidā* to go with *palǽstrā* (thus -ā, not -ă), indicating the temporal aspect (and I believe *dum* should be taken as *whilst*). Due to the construction with *dum*, I chose the past imperfect for *es* rather than the present tense. Considering *dum*:

> 556. Dum (while) regularly takes the present indicative to denote continued action in past time. In translating, the English imperfect must generally be used.[*](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dum-d%C5%8Dnec-and-quoad)

I cannot, though, for the life of me explain the short vowel in *lūdis*. I take it to be a poetic/historic accusative plural of lūdus, which should be *lūdīs*, though with my current analysis of the metre, that would be wrong. What is going on here? The interpretation of this might force a different translation, for which I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a second-person singular verb form *lūdis,* “you play” (*lūdō, lūdere*).

Comment: This answer is so simple and straightforward, I am nonplussed. My lesson for the day: Do not read to much into other translations, especially not when you have already decided there are errors in it. I presume this then would be a correct translation of the final line: *You play and are a woman amongst / mixing with naked men.* And considering the grammatical comment on dum, it should probably be rendered as *played* and *were*.